# What's the right way to provide a backtrace for an eval within `class << self`?

Tags: ruby, eval, backtrace

I'm working with a gem that dynamically defines some methods on a class, similar to this:

```
class << self
  some_strings.each do |string|
    eval <<-RUBY
      def #{string}
      ....
      end
    RUBY
  end
end
```

Any exceptions raised in those dynamically-defined methods have unhelpful backtraces; they lead to something like `(eval):2` instead of the actual line number.

I'd like to modify this code along the lines of:

```
eval <<-RUBY, nil, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
```

... in order to get nicer backtraces.

However, unlike `class_eval` and `instance_eval`, plain old `eval` has an optional `binding` parameter, and I'm not sure if it's a good idea to pass `nil` to it, as I show above.

It does seem to work, and the [documentation for eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) says the binding is optional:

```
If binding is given, which must be a Binding object, the evaluation is 
performed in its context.
```

Still, I'd love some helpful explanation, since I don't yet have a good grasp on bindings and dynamic evaluation.

**What's the right way to dynamically evaluate code within a `class << self` block and ensure useful backtraces?**

Answer (score 1):

Bindings aren't quite the solution you're looking for, since all those do is change the context of the `eval` and it's already in the context that you want.

A better practice is to avoid `eval`ing strings as much as possible. Ruby has a good number of metaprogramming helper methods that let you avoid string evals in all but the rarest cases.

In your specific example, it looks like `Module#define_method` or `Object#define_singleton_method` might be useful.

Comment: While I would never use `eval` on something that user input could affect, I think [this post](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/eval_isnt_quite_pure_evil) makes the case well that it's useful in some cases.

Comment: But you said so yourself why eval is bad: by throwing all of your code into a string, you rob Ruby of its usually helpful backtraces. Using metaprogramming methods lets Ruby do a better job of understanding your code.

Comment: The article you posted is also out of date. In Ruby 1.9.3, `super` behaves as expected inside `define_method` and the closure approach performs about 4 times faster than using `eval`.

Comment: good point about backtraces. Can you show a benchmark for the performance difference?

Comment: Alright, I made some mistakes on my first test. The `super` gotcha does still hold and using `eval` performs faster: by 3 hundredths of a second over 1,000,000 trials. So for an imperceptible performance boost, you get to drop some parentheses and your code no longer has good backtraces. Don't use `eval`.

Comment: I think you're right if we're only talking 1.9 and up, but I've just tried to apply this to a library that needs to work for 1.8 also. Since it doesn't support optional block arguments, I'd have to do `define_method('foo') do |*args|`, which is less readable than `(user, options = {})`.

Comment: Update: An article showing "`define_method` is generally better for performance" : http://tenderlovemaking.com/2013/03/03/dynamic_method_definitions.html